# How can I use Solve or NSolve on an equation written as a function

Tags: equation-solving

I tend to store all of my equations as functions so that I can easily use or refer to them later if needed. However, it seems that Solve doesn't work on these.

```
[IN]   Solve[3 x + 5 == 11, x]

[OUT]  {{x -> 2}}
```

This is the expected behavior. But when I try to use a function,

```
[IN]   f[x_] = 3 x + 5
       f[2] (* Function is correctly definied *)
       Solve[f[x] == 11, x] (* Should result in {x -> 2} *)

[OUT]  5 + 3 x
       11
       {}
```

The solution set is empty. I know there is an `RSolve` but I don't think this is what I want, as I'm simply trying to substitute the equation for the function, not find a solution that is a function.

Comment: @Moo Could you post exactly what you entered? I'm running MMA 10 on Win7. I'm not sure what you mean by "Enter `f[x]` on its own line first". Even if I evaluate the line with the function definition before using it in `Solve` I get the same result.

Comment: @Moo I think I found the problem. `f[x]` was evaluating to `0`, even after I assigned it an expression. Entering `Clear[f]` seemed to correct it. I'm not sure what I had done to cause me to be unable to change the expression stored in `f`. Does the `:=` do something different than `=`?. Thanks.